# Unable to compile "hello world" program with Swift on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: swift, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Using Ubuntu 14.04

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

and trying to compile a hello world Swift program.

```
print("Hello World!")
```

I have verified the download:

```
 gpg --verify swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-10-a-ubuntu14.04.tar.gz.sig
gpg: Signature made Thu 10 Dec 2015 07:17:37 PM PST using RSA key ID 412B37AD
gpg: Good signature from "Swift Automatic Signing Key #1 <swift-infrastructure@swift.org>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 7463 A81A 4B2E EA1B 551F  FBCF D441 C977 412B 37AD
```

But when I try and compile the hello world program I get this error:

```
> swiftc hello_world.swift 
<unknown>:0: error: opening import file for module 'SwiftShims': No such file or directory
```

If I start up the Swift REPL I get a similar error:

```
~$ swift
Welcome to Swift version 2.2-dev (LLVM 7bae82deaa, Clang 53d04af5ce, Swift 5995ef2acd). Type :help for assistance.
  1> y = 6
opening import file for module 'SwiftShims': No such file or directory
  1>
```

If I follow the instructions [given here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/122189/introduction-to-open-source-swift-on-linux) on using "swift build" versus "swiftc" for compiling a Hello World Swift program, I get a different error:

```
$ swift build
<unknown>:0: error: opening import file for module 'Swift': No such file or directory
swift-build: exit(1): ["/home/scooter/Programs/Swift/V2.2/bin/swiftc", "--driver-mode=swift", "-I", "/home/scooter/Programs/Swift/V2.2/lib/swift/pm", "-L", "/home/scooter/Programs/Swift/V2.2/lib/swift/pm", "-lPackageDescription", "/home/scooter/code/swift/helloworld-project/Package.swift"]
```

Executing the interpreter:

```
$ swift hello_world.swift
```

gives

```
<unknown>:0: error: opening import file for module 'SwiftShims': No such file or directory
```

strace gets an error trying to run swift:

```
$ strace  -o /tmp/swift.log -- swift <(echo '1 + 1')
<unknown>:0: error: opening import file for module 'SwiftShims': No such file or directory
```

> open("/home/user/Programs/Swift/V2.2/lib/swift/linux/x86_64/SwiftShims.swiftmodule",
>   O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Having same issue with Mint LInux 17.3. Using Swift REPL.  `Welcome to Swift version 2.2-dev (LLVM 46be9ff861, Clang 4deb154edc, Swift 778f82939c). Type :help for assistance.
  1> y = 6
opening import file for module 'SwiftShims': No such file or directory
  1> y = 6
error: The AST context is in a fatal error state.`

Comment: @cdplayer I got the same result. I will add it to the question.

Comment: This seems like it might be a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077880/swift-on-linux-make-very-first-step-work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077880/swift-on-linux-make-very-first-step-work). Do any of those answers help you?

Comment: @TwoStraws Two don't. Of the three answers, one is just a note and the responder says he has the same problem. The final answer says that he solved the problem by verifying his download  file with gpg and I have done that as shown above. Will look further at the other.

Comment: @TwoStraws The other answerer says that they have no problems on their system and suggests the questioner may have a problem with either a bad download file  or he has something wrong with his Ubuntu system. I don't think my download file is bad as I performed their verification and I had the same error on their latest two releases. As far as my Ubuntu being bad, I really don't want to re-install Ubuntu because I can't compile a Swift program and I would want to first hear more of an argument as to why that is the reason.

Comment: An strace from a "working" Ubuntu system, one where the error doesn't occur, also reports that the SwiftShims.swiftmodule file can't be found.  I have placed the strace output from my "working" Ubuntu at https://gist.github.com/omniprog/1226b54071f8bb43cf9d.  You may want to compare it to the strace output from a system where the error is observed.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for adding as an answer what should have really been a comment content-wise, but it is a little too long for a comment.

As far as I can tell, this is indeed the same problem as described in [Swift on Linux: Make very first step work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077880/swift-on-linux-make-very-first-step-work).  I have been looking into this myself in my spare time, but no luck so far.  The user who asked the other question has been pursuing it and has some interesting recent updates there.

A few things to try:

See if the swift interpreter works.  Just type `swift hello_world.swift` and see what happens.  I don't think it will work.  If it does not, then run the `strace` command as follows:

`strace  -o /tmp/swift.log -- swift <(echo '1 + 1')`

and look at `/tmp/swift.log`.  See what files cannot be found, especially near the end of the output.  Warning: even on a system where the error doesn't happen (I haven't been able to reproduce it yet), the `strace` output shows a lot of `No such file...` errors.

You can also try swift and swiftrc with the -v option to enable verbose output and see if you notice anything suspicious.

Update 1/2/2016:

The question referenced earlier has been updated with a possible solution to the problem: get rid of non-standard installations of gcc, g++, libgcc, and libstdc++.  Please see the comments in the other question.

Update 1/3/2016:

Using the clues from the discussion on the other question, I've been able to reproduce the problem by installing gcc-5.1.0 from source and pre-pending the location of the newly-installed libstdc++.so.6 to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.

The problem could be solved as follows:
1) Figure out where `libstdc++.so.6` from the older package is installed. On my system:

```
user@ubuntu14:~$ dpkg -l | grep libstdc++
ii  libstdc++-4.8-dev:amd64            4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04             amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++6:amd64                   4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04             amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3

user@ubuntu14:~$ dpkg -L libstdc++6 | grep libstdc++.so
    /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

2) Prepend the location of `libstdc++.so.6` to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

3) Double-check that the swift binary is using the correct shared library:

```
user@ubuntu14:~$ ldd `which swift` | grep libstdc++
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdd1476b000)
```

Now Swift should work without the error in question.

Comment: Trying to run the interpreter gets an error and strace gives: open ( "/home/user/Programs/Swift/V2.2/lib/swift/linux/x86_64/SwiftShims.swiftmodule", O_RDONLY ) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)  I think the error is related to my having installed g++ 4.9 from a non-standard repository (not available in default Ubuntu repository)  as James D also  ran into.

Comment: There are tons of "No such file..." errors in my strace output, even though it seems to work for me.  I think SwiftShims.swiftmodule is one of the files not found on my system, either, but I'd have to double check.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a non standard install using a PPA or any libraries for the build chain built from source? Particularly libstdc++. Please see my answer for [Swift on Linux: Make very first step work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077880/swift-on-linux-make-very-first-step-work).

Comment: I did set a different PPA to install g++ 4.9